# Use of the Smart Health Card for purposes other than vaccination records

Tags: hl7-fhir

The Smart Health Card seems to support only vaccination records, but does it support other uses?
（Other than the following）

【Credential Types】
`https://smarthealth.cards#health-card`
`https://smarthealth.cards#immunization`
`https://smarthealth.cards#covid19`
`https://smarthealth.cards#laboratory`

Comment: Whatever card that is: why not ask whoever maintains it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see https://spec.smarthealth.cards/

Any FHIR data may be included in a SMART Health Card as long as the payload is small enough -- but you generally want a use case specific profile to establish the data requirements and privacy preserving design choices.